# Jquery multiple radio buttons with the same name change event

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I have eight radio buttons that I get their values from the database.
I want to display the 'Indicator' field on change event

Controller :

```
ViewBag.indicator = db.Info.ToList();
return View();
```

View :

```
 @if (ViewBag.indicator != null)
 {
      foreach (var ind in ViewBag.indicator)
      {
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
              <input name="indicator" type="radio" id="@ind.id" value="@ind.ID" class="radio-col-blue-grey" />
              <label for="@ind.ID">@ind.Indicator</label>
          </div>
      }
 }
```

Jquery:

```
$("input[name=indicator]:radio").change(function () {
     var info = $('input[name=indicator]:checked').val();
     alert(info);
});
```

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: And what is your issue? No alert? Wrong value? Or what??? Is the change event bound?!...

Comment: I get nothing,  and no errors in the console

Comment: You probably try to bind event before element is available in the DOM. At first try wrapping it in document ready

Comment: Yes I have it inside document ready but I still have the same problem

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) which shows the actual problem because your script works: https://jsfiddle.net/8r0suw8z/

Comment: And what about delegating event, e.g: `$(document).on('change', "input[name=indicator]:radio", function() {
  var info = $('input[name=indicator]:checked').val();
  alert(info);
});
`

Comment: It worked when I removed it from document ready and I copied it in a function and I called it from "onchange".

Comment: Like this : <input name="indicator" type="radio" id="@ind.id" value="@ind.ID" class="radio-col-blue-grey"  onchange="onchangeRadio()" />